# Kendo UI Grid one column does not display data

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a `Kendo UI grid` that works great in development.  When I deploy it to production, the data in just one of the columns (Salesperson) does not appear.  I get no error at all.  When I view source, the td is just empty.  I've used Stackoverflow for years, never asked a question before. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
<script>
    $("#gridDirectSOsWithoutPOs").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: function(options) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "salesorder_home.aspx/GetDirectSOsWithoutPOs",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function(data) {
                            options.success(data);
                            $("tr", "#gridDirectSOsWithoutPOs").each(function(idx, elem) {
                                var valCell2 = $(":nth-child(2)", elem).html();
                                if (valCell2 < 90) {
                                    $(":nth-child(2)", elem).addClass('redCell');
                                }
                            });
                        },
                        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert(xhr.responseText);
                        }
                    });
                }
            },
            schema: {
                data: "d",
                model: {
                    fields: {
                        PromiseDate: {
                            type: "date"
                        },
                        DaysLeft: {
                            type: "number"
                        },
                        SODate: {
                            type: "date"
                        },
                        Salesperson: {
                            type: "string"
                        },
                        OrderNumber: {
                            type: "number"
                        },
                        OrderAmount: {
                            type: "number"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        filterable: false,
        sortable: true,
        columns: [{
            field: "PromiseDate",
            title: "Promise Date",
            template: "#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(PromiseDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'M/d/yyyy') #",
            width: 80,
            attributes: {
                style: "text-align: center;"
            }
        }, {
            field: "DaysLeft",
            title: "Days Left",
            width: 45,
            attributes: {
                style: "text-align: center;"
            }
        }, {
            field: "SODate",
            title: "SO Date",
            template: "#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(SODate, 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'M/d/yyyy') #",
            width: 80,
            attributes: {
                style: "text-align: center;"
            }
        }, {
            field: "Customer",
            title: "Customer",
            template: '<a href="javascript:window.location(\'../customer/customer.aspx?number=#=Number#\')" style="text-decoration: none;">#=Customer#</a>',
            width: 150
        }, {
            field: "VendorCountry",
            title: "Vendor Country",
            width: 55,
            attributes: {
                style: "text-align: center;"
            }
        }, {
            field: "Salesperson",
            title: "Salesperson",
            width: 120
                //attributes: {
                //    style: "text-align: center;"
                //}
        }, {
            field: "OrderNumber",
            title: "Order Number",
            template: '<a href="javascript:window.location(\'../salesorder/salesorder.aspx?ordnum=#=OrderNumber#\')" style="text-decoration: none;">#=OrderNumber#</a>',
            width: 60,
            attributes: {
                style: "text-align: center;"
            }
        }, {
            field: "OrderAmount",
            title: "Order Amount",
            format: "{0:n0}",
            width: 70,
            attributes: {
                style: "text-align: right;"
            }
        }]
    });
</script>

<div id="gridDirectSOsWithoutPOs" class="k-grid"></div>
```

Comment: Dump your request data result for us(both, from dev and production) if possible(in a pastebin or something). This way is hard to tell you what issue can be.

Comment: Well here's the dump from development.  Now I need to figure out how to get the same dump from production.  May need to write code to ajax it back to the server and save a file?

[link]http://pastebin.com/A0qFJYQt

Comment: You could use fiddler or some similar network sniffer to get the data?

Comment: Short look on your code and I didn't notice anything strange. Also development data looks ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all, the problem appears to have fixed itself.  We did have some serious network issues last week where trust relationships between many servers were broken.  Thought they were all fixed but I'm chalking this up to "lingering issues" for now.  I'm going to double check that I'm properly handling all possible nulls this morning and move on.  @Icepickle:  Fiddler!  It's right there on my task bar.  I use it so seldom I forget it's there.  Thanks again!